# Join each term with list of keywords

Tags: r, split

Probably a simple problem and you can help me quickly.

I have a vector with all the terms contained in a list of keywords. Now I want to join each term with all keywords that contain this term. Here's an example

```
vec <- c("small", "boat", "river", "house", "tour", "a", "on", "the", "houseboat", …)
keywords <- c("small boat tour", "a house on the river", "a houseboat", …)
```

The expected result looks like:

```
              keywords     terms
       small boat tour     small
       small boat tour      boat
       small boat tour      tour
  a house on the river         a
  a house on the river     house
  a house on the river        on
  a house on the river       the
  a house on the river     river
           a houseboat         a
           a houseboat  houseboat
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `expand.grid` to get all combinations, wrap the words of `vec` in word boundaries, `grepl` and filter, i.e.

```
df1 <- expand.grid(vec, keywords)
df1[mapply(grepl, paste0('\\b' ,df1$Var1, '\\b'), df1$Var2),]

        Var1                 Var2
1      small      small boat tour
2       boat      small boat tour
5       tour      small boat tour
12     river a house on the river
13     house a house on the river
15         a a house on the river
16        on a house on the river
17       the a house on the river
24         a          a houseboat
27 houseboat          a houseboat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_join` using `stringr::str_detect` as the matching function, and adding `\\b` word boundaries to each word in `vec`.

```r
vec <- data.frame(terms = c("small", "boat", "river", "house", "tour", "a", "on", "the", "houseboat"))
keywords <- data.frame(keywords = c("small boat tour", "a house on the river", "a houseboat"))

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(keywords, vec, by = c("keywords" = "terms"), 
                            match_fun = \(x, y) stringr::str_detect(x, paste0("\\b", y, "\\b")))
```

output

```r
               keywords     terms
1       small boat tour     small
2       small boat tour      boat
3       small boat tour      tour
4  a house on the river     river
5  a house on the river     house
6  a house on the river         a
7  a house on the river        on
8  a house on the river       the
9           a houseboat         a
10          a houseboat houseboat
```

Answer (score 2):

A way can be using `strsplit` and `intersect`.

```
. <- lapply(strsplit(keywords, " ", TRUE), intersect, vec)
data.frame(keywords = rep(keywords, lengths(.)), terms = unlist(.))
#               keywords     terms
#1       small boat tour     small
#2       small boat tour      boat
#3       small boat tour      tour
#4  a house on the river         a
#5  a house on the river     house
#6  a house on the river        on
#7  a house on the river       the
#8  a house on the river     river
#9           a houseboat         a
#10          a houseboat houseboat
```

In case`vec` contains *all* keywords there is no need for join.

```
. <- lapply(strsplit(keywords, " ", TRUE), unique)
data.frame(keywords = rep(keywords, lengths(.)), terms = unlist(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected result can be reproduced by

```
library(data.table)
data.table(keywords)[, .(terms = tstrsplit(keywords, "\\W+")), by = keywords]
```

> ```
>                 keywords     terms
>  1:      small boat tour     small
>  2:      small boat tour      boat
>  3:      small boat tour      tour
>  4: a house on the river         a
>  5: a house on the river     house
>  6: a house on the river        on
>  7: a house on the river       the
>  8: a house on the river     river
>  9:          a houseboat         a
> 10:          a houseboat houseboat
> ```

This is a rather simple answer which is an interpretation of OP's sentence

> I have a vector with all the terms contained in a list of keywords.

The important point is *all the terms*. So, it is assumed that we just can split the keywords into separate terms.

Note that the regex `\\W+` is used to separate the terms in case there are more than one *non-word* characters between the terms, e.g., `", "`.

---

However, in case the vector does *not* contain *all* terms *intentionally* we need to subset the result, e.g.

```
vec <- c("small", "boat", "river", "house", "tour", "houseboat")
data.table(keywords)[, .(terms = tstrsplit(keywords, "\\W+")), by = keywords][
  terms %in% vec]
```

> ```
>                keywords     terms
> 1:      small boat tour     small
> 2:      small boat tour      boat
> 3:      small boat tour      tour
> 4: a house on the river     house
> 5: a house on the river     river
> 6:          a houseboat houseboat
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R one-liner with `strsplit` + `stack`

```
> with(keywords, rev(stack(setNames(strsplit(keywords, " "), keywords))))
                    ind    values
1       small boat tour     small
2       small boat tour      boat
3       small boat tour      tour
4  a house on the river         a
5  a house on the river     house
6  a house on the river        on
7  a house on the river       the
8  a house on the river     river
9           a houseboat         a
10          a houseboat houseboat
```